# Storing set of non-overlapping ranges and finding whether a value is present in any one of the ranges strictly

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, binary-tree, range

I have a set of ranges :

Range1 ---- (0-10)

Range2 ---- (15-25)

Range3 ---- (100-1000)  and likewise.
I would like to have only the bounds stored since storing large ranges , it would be efficient.

Now I need to search for a number , say 14 . In this case, 14 is not present in any of the ranges whereas (say a number) 16 is present in one of the ranges.

I would need a function

```
bool search(ranges, searchvalue)
{
    if searchvalues present in any of the ranges
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

How best can this be done ? This is strictly non-overlapping and the important criteria is that the search has to be most efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to represent ranges as a pair of values and define a suitable comparison function. The following should consider one range less than another if its bounds are smaller and there is no overlap. As a side effect, this comparison function doesn't let you store overlapping ranges in the set.

To look up an integer `n`, it can be treated as a range `[n, n]`

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::pair<int, int> Range;
struct RangeCompare
{
    //overlapping ranges are considered equivalent
    bool operator()(const Range& lhv, const Range& rhv) const
    {   
        return lhv.second < rhv.first;
    } 
};

bool in_range(const std::set<Range, RangeCompare>& ranges, int value)
{
    return ranges.find(Range(value, value)) != ranges.end();
}

int main()
{
    std::set<Range, RangeCompare> ranges;
    ranges.insert(Range(0, 10));
    ranges.insert(Range(15, 25));
    ranges.insert(Range(100, 1000));
    std::cout << in_range(ranges, 14) << ' ' << in_range(ranges, 16) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `RangeCompare` does not satisfy the `strict week ordering` requirement by the specification.

Comment: @fefe: Could you bring a counter-example (assuming `x.first <= x.second` - the range may be encapsulated as needed to guarantee this)?

Comment: strict week ordering requires transitivity for `equiv` defined as `!comp(a,b) && !comp(b,a)`: `equiv(a,b) && equiv(b,c) --> equiv(a,c)`. For your `RangeCompare`, `(10,20) '==' (15,25) && (15,25) '==' (21,30)`, but `(10,20) '!=' (21,30)`.

Comment: I'm going to have non-overlapping ranges. So, this shouldn't be a problem. That's one of the reason, why I dint look into that. I'm looking for performant search in non-overlapping ranges. This should fit the criteria being O(log(n)).

Comment: You can't guarantee that the container won't allow overlapping ranges to be inserted, because as @fefe says the container's requirements have been violated. Strict weak ordering can be guaranteed by changing the comparator to `lhv.first < rhv.first && lhv.second < rhv.first`. This is no different to the proposed solution, except now the container will have defined behaviour. Overlapping ranges will be considered equal and therefore cannot be inserted.

Answer (score 4):

You could put something together based on `std::map` and `std::map::upper_bound`:

Assuming you have

```
std::map<int,int> ranges; // key is start of range, value is end of range
```

You could do the following:

```
bool search(const std::map<int,int>& ranges, int searchvalue)
{
    auto p = ranges.upper_bound(searchvalue); 
      // p->first > searchvalue
    if(p == ranges.begin())
        return false;
    --p;  // p->first <= searchvalue
    return searchvalue >= p->first && searchvalue <= p->second;
}
```

I'm using C++11, if you use C++03, you'll need to replace "auto" by the proper iterator type.

EDIT: replaced pseudo-code inrange() by explicit expression in return statement.

Comment: What do you mean by inrange()

Comment: @Dumb I was just too lazy to spell out ``searchvalue >= p->first && searchvalue <= p->second`` or ``searchvalue >= p->first && searchvalue < p->second``, depending on your preference. I thought that would pass as proper pseudo-code.

Comment: What order will the search be ?

Comment: @Dumb Time complexity is O(log n).

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to handle this is through so called [interval trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). Basically, you augment an ordinary red-black tree with additional information so that each node x contains an interval x.int and the key of x is the low endpoint, x.int.low, of the interval. Each node x also contains a value x.max, which is the maximum value of any interval endpoint stored in the subtree rooted at x. Now you can determine x.max given interval x.int and the max values of node x’s children as follows:

x.max = max(x.int.high, x.left.max, x.right.max)

This implies that, with *n* intervals,  insertion and deletion run in O(lg *n*) time. In fact, it is possible to update the max attributes after a rotation in O(1) time. Here is how to search for an element i in the interval tree T

```
INTERVAL-SEARCH(T, i)
x = T:root
while x is different from T.nil and i does not overlap x.int
   if x.left is different from T.nil and x.left.max is greater than or equal to i.low 
      x = x.left
  else 
      x = x.right 
return x
```

The complexity of the search procedure is O(lg *n*) as well.
To see why, see CLRS [Introduction to algorithms](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=11866), chapter 14 (Augmenting Data Structures).

Comment: I'm already trying to implement interval trees and see if there is any improvement. Between, Visitor's answer looks to me of the order of O(log(n)). So shouldn't be any different than that considering I'm going to have only non-overlapping ranges. Insertion or  updation is gonna be the difference. But my evaluation of performance in this , is going to be the search.

Answer (score 2):

A good solution can be as the following. It is O(log(n)).

A critical condition is non overlapping ranges.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

template <typename T> struct z_range
{
        T s , e ;
        z_range ( T const & s,T const & e ) : s(s<=e?s:e), e(s<=e?e:s)
        {
        }
};

template <typename T> bool operator < (z_range<T> const & x , z_range<T> const & y )
{
    if ( x.e<y.s)
        return true ;
    return false ;
}

int main(int , char *[])
{
    std::set<z_range<int> > x;
    x.insert(z_range<int>(20,10));
    x.insert(z_range<int>(30,40));
    x.insert(z_range<int>(5,9));
    x.insert(z_range<int>(45,55));

    if (x.find(z_range<int>(15,15)) != x.end() )
        std::cout << "I have it" << std::endl ;
    else
        std::cout << "not exists" << std::endl ;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have ranges ri = [ai, bi]. You could sort all the `ai` and put them into an array and search for `x` having `x >= ai and ai minimal` using binary search.

After you found this element you have to check whether `x <= bi`.

This is suitable if you have big numbers. If, on the other hand, you have either a lot of memory or small numbers, you can think about putting those ranges into a bool array. This may be suitable if you have a lot of queries:

```
bool ar[];
ar[0..10] = true;
ar[15..25] = true;
// ...

bool check(int searchValues) {
  return ar[searchValues];
}
```

Comment: This would mean having two searches over the range. Isn't there a simplified way and faster way to do this.

Comment: @Dumb: In your question you didn't mention that you only have the bounds.

Comment: No, you can do that in one pass. Just store the `bi` near the `ai` using a struct for example.

Comment: @jrok I edited it. Thanks. I dint think it would be misunderstood.

duedl0r, i would try and see how efficient is. Every milli second is very important and I want to make sure that its the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Since the ranges are non-overlapping the only thing left to do is performing a search within the range that fit's the value. If the values are ordered within the ranges, searching is even simpler. [Here](http://www.cprogramming.com/discussionarticles/sorting_and_searching.html) is a summary of search algorithms.

With respect to C++ you also can use [algorithms](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search/) from STL or even functions provided by the containers, e. g. `set::find`.

Comment: To use something like set::find,I have to store the all the elements of the range in the set whereas I would like to store only the start and end point of the all the ranges which would better if there are huge ranges.

Comment: Ok, but you said that a value can be present or not, so where is this value stored then?

Comment: I would store only the bounds of the range and would like to search accordingly.

Comment: So then what do you mean by "In this case, 14 is not present in any of the ranges whereas (say a number) 16 is present in one of the ranges."?

Comment: I mean when I search for 14. It doesn't come within any of the ranges while a 16 fits in one of the ranges.

Comment: Ok then, i didn't get it ... sorry for that, forget the answer, wrong topic ;)

Answer (score 0):

So, this assumes the ranges are continous (i.e range [100,1000] contains all numbers between 100 and 1000):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

bool is_in_ranges(std::map<int, int> ranges, int value)
{
    return
    std::find_if(ranges.begin(), ranges.end(),
        [&](std::pair<int,int> pair)
        {
             return value >= pair.first && value <= pair.second;
        }
    ) != ranges.end();
}

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> ranges;
    ranges[0] = 10;
    ranges[15] = 25;
    ranges[100] = 1000;

    std::cout << is_in_ranges(ranges, 14) << '\n';  // 0
    std::cout << is_in_ranges(ranges, 16) << '\n';  // 1
}
```

In C++03, you'd need a functor instead of a lambda function:

```
struct is_in {
    is_in(int x) : value(x) {}
    bool operator()(std::pair<int, int> pair)
    {
        return value >= pair.first && value <= pair.second;
    }
private:
    int value;
};

bool is_in_ranges(std::map<int, int> ranges, int value)
{
    return
    std::find_if(ranges.begin(), ranges.end(), is_in(value)) != ranges.end();
}
```

Comment: Perfect I would tweak it to fit my requirements. Seems to me a genuine option. How performant its going to be is what I'm going to find out. Anyidea, what order does find_if work in ?

Comment: @Dumb I think `find_if` has got O(n) complexity.

Comment: can we tweak this into the binary search for better performance ?

Comment: @Dumb `map::find()` is implemented as binary search, I think. It would be a bit trickier since it doesn't take a predicate as argument. Unless you've got a big number of ranges, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Using this std::binary_search () , it would I guess.

Comment: Yep,perfect. that's what i have been trying out now with find.